# MATLAB: ??? Undefined function or method 'sprint' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab, char, printf, decimal

I´m trying to show 16 decimal place of a result. The code I put is this

```
clear x;
x = 0.245;
1-x+1/2*x.^2-1/6*x.^3+1/24*x.^4
sprint('%0.16f', ans)
```

Matlab give me this answer

```
ans =

0.7827

??? Undefined function or method 'sprint' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

I have two question:

1. What happen? I think I used it before and I had no problems with 'sprintf' for show a   result with several decimal places.
2. What can I do to show more decimal places?

Thank you!

Comment: Please re-edit your comment so your Matlab code shows up as code- indent it by four spaces in the editor.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM !!! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM !!! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM !!!

Comment: `Undefined function or method X` usually means `X is misspelled`

Comment: @Mikhail: Sorry, I´ll try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf` formats data into a string; it does not display it for output. Furthermore, it's `sprintf`, not `sprint`, which is the function you've typed- and that MATLAB is complaining about. (It doesn't know what `sprint` is, but it knows about `sprintf`.)

If you mean to save ans to a string as a number to 16 decimal places, use `sprintf`. To just display it, which I think is what you want, use `printf` instead. In either case, the issue is clear; you forgot the `f` in `sprintf`!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think 'vpa' this help me to show more decimal places

```
clear x;
clear expresion;
x = 0.245;
expresion = 1-x+1/2*x.^2-1/6*x.^3+1/24*x.^4
%sprint('%0.16f', ans)
vpa(expresion,16)
```

**EDIT:**
and this is the matlab answer:

```
expresion =

0.7827


ans =

.7827116041927082
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not use `sprint` before.  There is no MATLAB intrinsic function called `sprint`, you ought to use `sprintf`.